# Chemical reactions at the synapse

Tags: literature, synapses

For my course project, I am thinking of listing out major chemical reactions that occur at synapses, along with their temporal characteristics.

I could not find any textbooks to use as a starting point, and Google did not help me either. I was hoping to receive help in finding a review paper or textbook about chemical computations at the synapse.

Comment: [Acetylcholinesterase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetylcholinesterase) is just one very important example of an enzyme in the synapse. Inhibiting this enzyme is how nerve gases and pesticides work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested it from the point of view of "chemical computations", you probably want literature which looks at signal transduction in detail. I would suggest [Marks' et al textbook on signal transduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0815342152). I have not yet read it through (it is on my list), but I liked the clear writing style of the introduction, and, as you can see from the table of contents, it does have chapters which address synapses and their neurotransmitters specifically.

I doubt that it will contain a complete list (there are several hundreds of compounds which can be considered to be neurotransmitters), but as an introductory textbook, it is likely to contain the major ones.